# shiny: includeHTML not playing nicely with navbarMenu

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Let's consider a simple shiny application with server.R and ui.R file. I'm just modifying RStudio's shiny template slightly:

server.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

  })

})
```

Now, as to the ui.R, I want to include two HTML files. These are generated by R Markdown, and I'll just call them test1 and test2. The code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
path1 <- "test1"
path2 <- "test2"

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

     # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id="tabs",
                  tabPanel("One",
                           plotOutput("distPlot")
                  ),
                 # navbarMenu("Simulation Features",
                             tabPanel("Two",
                                      HTML("Test"),
                                      includeHTML(path1)
                             ),
                             tabPanel("Three",
                                      includeHTML(path2)
                             )
                #  )
    ))
  )
))
```

Note that the navbarMenu line (and the corresponding closing bracket) is commented out. This code runs as expected on both Windows and Mac, as well as on shiny server.

However, if I uncomment the navbarMenu line, then the code only runs on the Mac. On Windows and shiny server, the navigation becomes unresponsible, i.e. you can click as much as you want, nothing happens.

As the problem occurs on Windows, here's the sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.10.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bitops_1.0-6  caTools_1.17  digest_0.6.4  httpuv_1.3.0 
[5] Rcpp_0.11.2   RJSONIO_1.3-0 tools_3.0.3   xtable_1.7-3
```

Does anyone else have this issue? Any workarounds, or should I file an issue on Github?

Thanks, Philipp

Answer (score 1):

Just use includeCSS()
(Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 21.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. There are two ways to address the issue:

1. Instead of includeHTML(), try includeMarkdown(). You may lose the format, but it will work.
2. Click the NavbarMenu, and then hit Space on keyboard, your tab-panels  will appear.

I'm still looking for the way to make it work with NavbarMenu and includeHTML at the same time though.